# Joi.js - how to require at least one boolean field to be true?

Tags: javascript, node.js, joi

I have a Joi schema where I want a conditional validation.  For object `example`, I have fields `a` and `b`.  At least one must be present and `true`, but neither is required to be present on its own.

This is the pseudocode for what I'd hope to accomplish, but I can't figure it out.

```
const example = Joi.object({
   a: Joi.boolean().optional().when('b', { is: /* null, missing, or false */, then: Joi.valid(true).required()}
   b: Joi.boolean().optional().when('a', { is: /* null, missing, or false */, then: Joi.valid(true).required()}
})
```

This is a legacy API - I am adding validations and have no flexibility to make up simpler, more flexible rules that work with what Joi makes easy (to me).

I can, optionally, use jsonschema -- but I am reluctant to do so at the moment since I've built out other validations using Joi and it would cost me a fair chunk of time.  I guess I could go with a partial schema there.  Shrug.

Tests:

```
schema.validate({ example: { a: false, b: false}}) // must fail
schema.validate({ example: { b: false}}) // must fail
schema.validate({ example: { a: false}}) // must fail
schema.validate({ example: { }}) // must fail
schema.validate({ example: { a: null, b: null }}) // must fail

schema.validate({ example: { a: true, b: null }}) // must PASS
schema.validate({ example: { a: null, b: true }}) // must PASS
schema.validate({ example: { a: true }}) // must PASS
schema.validate({ example: { b: true }}) // must PASS
```

Answer (score 0):

After struggling for a good while, I came up with this:

```
    b: Joi.boolean().optional(),
    a: Joi.boolean().when('b', { is: Joi.equal(null, false), then: Joi.valid(true).required() })
      .messages({
        'any.required': 'one or both of example.a or example.b must equal === true',
        'any.only': 'one or both of example.a or example.b must equal === true',
      })
```

It passes all my tests.

[EDIT]

I pulled this out to a function...

```
const oneMustBePresentAndTrue = (firstProperty, secondProperty) => {
  const container = {}
  container[firstProperty] = Joi.boolean().optional()
  const errorMessage = `one or both of {{#label}} or {..number.key}.${firstProperty} must equal === true`
  container[secondProperty] = Joi.boolean().when(firstProperty, {
    is: Joi.equal(null, false),
    then: Joi.valid(true).required()
  }).messages({
    'any.required': errorMessage,
    'any.only': errorMessage
  })
  return container
}
```